# How can I insert math equations in word from php?

Tags: math, docx, equation, phpword, mathtype

I need to automatically generate word documents with mathematical expressions using php.
Better to use Microsoft equation, MathType or word's 07+ equation editor.
I tried to use phpword's function addObject() to insert MathType *.eps file as OLE but it filetype not support.
How I should do it?

```
    $word = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $word->addSection();
    $section->addObject('formulas/Eqn1.eps');
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($word, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('docs/helloWorld.docx');
```

Error: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\InvalidObjectException

If I tried add as math:

```
$section->addText('
    <w:p w:rsidR="00D14CAF" w:rsidRDefault="00A07C15">
        <m:oMathPara>
            <m:oMath>
                <m:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <m:t>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</m:t>
                </m:r>
            </m:oMath>
        </m:oMathPara>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
        ');
```

*.docx doesn't open (error)

Comment: Please show us the what you have tried so far, that is post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The file does not open cause there's xml tag elements in the text.
I needed to insert equations into a document and the easiest way was to render the equation using [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) then save an image with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and insert with phpWord `addImage()`. I hope this helps.

Comment: could you guide me how to do so? or if there is any other solution to print mathML equation to word

Answer (score 0):

adding answer for new developers.

php-docx library can help here, here is an example

https://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/word-content/add-math-OMML-Word-document-with-PHP